# How to create a JSON object from two vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, json, vector

I'm new to JSON,c++ and C++ REST SDK so I'm struggling about creating a JSON object from two vectors right now. 
What I have right now: 2 vectors containing dimension data

```
 std::vector<glm::vec3> bookDimension{
    glm::vec3(x1,       y1,   z1),  // element in vector are float type
    glm::vec3(x2,       y2,   z2),  // element in vector are float type
    glm::vec3(x3,       y3,   z3),  // element in vector are float type
};
std::vector<glm::vec3> containerDimension{
    glm::vec3(x4,       y4,   z4), // element in vector are float type
};
```

I want to use these 2 vectors and create a single JSON object, the structure of the JSON object hopefully is like this

```
{"b":[
     [x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3]
     ],
 "c":[[x4,y4,z4]
     ]
 }
```

I'm not sure about how to initialize the correct obj. Below is what I can reach so far

```
json::value jsonObj;
std::vector<glm::vec3>::const_iterator it = bookDimension.begin(), end = boxDimension.end();
for (; it != end; ++it) {
    (jsonObj["b"][it][0]) = it->x;
    jsonObj["b"][it][1] = it->y;
    jsonObj["b"][it][2] = it->z;
}
```

And the error is 
web::json::value::operator[](const std::string &key) (declared at line xxxx of "..\json.h") is in accessible

Appreciate any help/hints in advance! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just iterate over the vectors and add each item to a string, adding the commas as needed. The only gotcha is the potential extra comma, which you can either fix with a guard condition or edit the string when you're done with a vector. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah, i was trying to do what you suggest but kind of confused about the initializing of JSON. Should I use JSON array? or just JSON value? Right now what I understand is making a parameter something like json::array jsonVector();  and auto iterate to assign value  jsonVector["b"][it][0] = it->x; jsonVector["b"][it][1] = it->y;

Comment: Please edit your question with something like, I tried <what you just commented> but it didn't work, I got this error <error>. Code is really hard to read in comments. Also I've never heard of json::array, if it's some library, you might want to mention that in your question too.

Comment: There is no json in the C++ standard. What are you using?

Comment: Im using the Casablanca ( C++ REST SDK) package.Sorry about not mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code from "the wiki" I'm guessing you're using microsoft's [c++ rest sdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk). If that's the case, it should work to do something like

```
json::value finalObject;
json::value bookDimJsonArray;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<bookDimension.size();i++){
    json::value vec3Array;
    vec3Array[0]=bookDimension[i].x;
    vec3Array[1]=bookDimension[i].y;
    vec3Array[2]=bookDimension[i].z;
    bookDimJsonArray[i]=vec3Array;
}
json::value containerDimJsonArray;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<containerDimension.size();i++){
    json::value vec3Array;
    vec3Array[0]=containerDimension[i].x;
    vec3Array[1]=containerDimension[i].y;
    vec3Array[2]=containerDimension[i].z;
    containerDimJsonArray[i]=vec3Array;
}
finalObject[L"b"]=bookDimJsonArray;
finalObject[L"c"]=containerDimJsonArray;
```

although you might want to use an object for the vec3 representation since the number of elements wont change (`vec3Obj[L"x"]=bookOrContainerDimension[i].x` etc.)

I'm pretty sure on my guess because the `L"string"` syntax is a Microsoft extension, but next time please post what library you're using, preferably in both the question and as a tag.

Incase I'm wrong, you could always just add to a string yourself, using a string and `+=`

Comment: I wrote my answer before I saw your comments on the refresh, but it looks like I guessed correctly

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve my problem. And yes your guess is correct.   I did update the question and tried to make it more clear now. It's my first time to post question, still need tons of things to learn.

Comment: sure, now you'll know for the next time you have a question. Good luck!